# Phone number search with PHP/MySQL - Best Practice?

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search, search-engine

I'm looking to build a yellowpages-esque search engine using PHP and a MySQL database. This database obviously stores names, addresses, and most importantly, phone numbers. I will be prompting the user to select which type of search they are performing so I can accurately cleanse and handle the input. For names/addresses I will most probably implement a Fulltext Search as it seems most appropriate?

For Phone numbers, however, I will be storing them as cleanly as possible (numeric characters only, no whitespace -- ie. (07)55 200 314 would be stored as 0755200314). I was wondering if there is a best practice for searching purely for numbers (ie. a simple LIKE '%$search%')? It is my understanding that a MySQL Fulltext search is not appropriate because it would require the user to input the entire phone number not just a partial (which I intend on providing matches for).

Any input on this topic would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry but... You want to implement substring phone search? As in, all phones that contain 123?

Comment: I can suggest to use php functions for that.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario - the search will only be called after a minimum  input of 5-6 digits (phone number length varies from 8-10 digits)

Answer (score 1):

Don't reinvent the wheel: use production ready and well tested solutions like http://sphinxsearch.com/ or some other search tools. Your database looks like rarely changing, but huge in size - the tools will index it once and then allow you to write robust queries for partial matches, ignoring typos, complex queries with results sorted by custom weights etc etc.

Comment: you're right, the database is going to be absolutely massive in size and quite static. I know of Sphinx, but have never used it myself, but is it appropriate for all types of data (text, varchar, int) ?

edit: Just did a bit of reading, Sphinx only appears to work on Strings. There's no inherent issue storing pure numbers as varchar/text?

Answer (score 0):

For `phone LIKE '2134%'` you don't need `FULLTEXT` index. It uses usual `BTREE` index. This way, user should input correct phone number from the very beginning.

Also `FULLTEXT` search implies limitations on word length. Not less that 4 chars (*if I'm not mistaken*). And it is not appropriate solution to search for phone numbers.

If I did a mistake in a phone number like: true number is *333-15-14* and user input *332-15-14*, right after *332* we have already another number, another range, and it will not match desired ones.